# Settings.settingsのプロパティ値取得に変数を使いたい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

■行いたい事

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Apple;
```

とすれば、`Settings.settings`で[名前]`Apple`に設定されている値を取得出来ます。

自分が行いたいのはこの[名前]の部分を直接指定ではなく、
変数で指定出来ないか考えています。

例えば[名前]`AppleAomori`,[名前]`AppleIwate`と言うような値が設定されている場合

```
string apple = "Apple";

string aomori = "Aomori";
string iwate = "Iwate";

string AomoRingo = apple + aomori;
string IwateRingo = apple + iwate;

Properties.Settings.Default.AomoRingo;
Properties.Settings.Default.IwateRingo;
```

当然これは`AomoRingo`の[名前]のプロパティを探しにいくので望む処理では無いです。
なんとかして変数か何かで読み込ませる方法は無いでしょうか？

■理由
なぜ、これを実現したいのかと言いますと、
コンボボックスとテキストボックスの連携を行いたいが為です。

この例で言う産地をコンボボックスで選べるようにして、
選んだ産地を`"apple"`と結合してそれに該当する値をテキストボックスに表示したいのです。
できるなら方法は別になんでもよいのですが...
どなたかご教授願います。

Comment: 直接の回答になるかわかりませんが、コンボの値でテキストを変えるサンプルを書いてみました。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/22144/9820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

インデクサ―でアクセスできます。

```
(string)Settings.Default[AomoriRingo]
```

Comment: @pgrhoさんへ
インデクサーと言うのもあるのですね～
うーんこちらはかなり短いので扱いやすそうです。
こちらも試してみたところ問題なく取得出来ました！
今回はこちらを使用してみたいと思います。

最後に、質問文の修正ありがとうございました～

Answer (score 0):

リフレクションを使うと次のように書けます。

```
using System.Reflection;

...

Type t = Properties.Settings.Default.GetType();
String value = (String)t.GetProperty(AomoRingo ).GetValue(Properties.Settings.Default, BindingFlags.Default, null,null,null);
```

`AomoRingo` の内容の文字列のプロパティをゲットしその値（文字列）を取り出しています。
`value`に`Properties.Settings.Default.AppleAomori`の値が得られます。

Comment: @BLUEPIXYさんへ
リフレクションと言う方法があるのですね！勉強になります。
実際に使ってみたところ問題なく習得できているようです。
ありがとうございました！